# NAT terminology DNAT: Is Dynamic NAT the same as Destination NAT?

Tags: networking, nat

The reason I ask this is that all the Comptia resources I have refer to DNAT as Dynamic NAT. A lot of online resources refer to DNAT as Destination NAT (destination ip header change) though no reference to Dynamic NAT.

So what I am clarifying, is Destination NAT and Dynamic NAT essentially the same DNAT term or different technically?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Dynamic NAT and Destination NAT are different.

DNAT actually stands for Destination Network Address Translation, not Dynamic Network Address Translation. Destination NAT changes the destination address in the IP header of a incoming packet. It may also change the destination port in the TCP or UDP headers. The  usage of this is to redirect incoming packets with a destination of a public address/port to a private IP address/port inside your network. And the opposite is SNAT, which occurs on Outgoing packets.

Dynamic NAT, on the other hand, is not common in smaller networks but is found within larger corporations/organisations with huge networks. The way dynamic NAT differs from static NAT is that where static NAT only maps one public IP address to private IP address, anddynamic NAT usually uses a group of available public IP addresses, known as a NAT pool.

**TL;DR: DNAT actually refers to Destination NAT, and Destination NAT and Dynamic NAT differ.**

Hope that helps

Comment: awesome good to know thanks. I'm still concerned though why Comptia certifications refer to DNAT as Dynamic NAT if what you say is technically correct in the industry. Can be confusing refering to DNAT if its known as 2 different things.